# Can I use a ternary in a PHP class method return statement?

Tags: php, return-value, ternary-operator

Can I do this?  (I can't test it at the moment to see for myself)

```
public function overSimplifiedTernaryTest($condition = false) {
    return ($condition) ? 'someString' : 'someOtherString';
}
```

Comment: Yes. (Commenting because this doesn't deserve rep points...)

Comment: This is a close-worthy question. :)

Comment: Is this conditional operator test really simplified?

Comment: Hey!  It's programming related.  And the answers settled my dispute!

Comment: You can test code samples at codepad.org

Comment: Never saw codepad before.  That's awesome! thanks!

Comment: There is also ideone.com, which is similar to codepad.

Comment: I know it works, but I thought it was a valid question. When I saw [this note](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) on PHP.org, it caused me to question when this might not work. _Note: Please note that the ternary operator is a statement, and that it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of a statement. This is important to know if you want to return a variable by reference. The statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b; in a return-by-reference function will therefore not work and a warning is issued in later PHP versions._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works and next time you can use [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) to test your code instead of asking question.

Your code : http://ideone.com/2oHkF

You can also refer to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1953/what-online-computer-language-interpreters-are-available-so-i-can-practice-progr) for additionnal online tool to test your code.

Comment: Actually TheMagician suggested codepad.org, and both of these are great.  Thanks!

Comment: @Stephen You can also look at the link I just added for other online tool to test your code.

Answer (score 4):

**This is working.**

Example:

```
class CClass
{
    public function overSimplifiedTernaryTest($condition = false)
    {
        return ($condition) ? 'someString' : 'someOtherString';
    }
}

$x = new CClass();
echo $x->overSimplifiedTernaryTest(false) . 
     '\r\n' . 
     $x->overSimplifiedTernaryTest(true);
delete $x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that.

[Example](http://ideone.com/yCYbr)

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator will return one value, which is what you then return from the function. This is why what you're trying to do will be no problem. It'll also work in other languages, you could do this in Javascript also for example.